# Os.walk not running?

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk

I'm trying to find a location of a file using `os.walk`
I've done so much googling and cannot find an answer to my problem.

Any code I write does not find my file, so I added a count to count how many things it's searching

```
import os
myfile = 'test.txt'
c = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\"):
    c+=1
    for name in files:
        c+=1
        blahblahblah
print(c)
```

No matter what i place inside the `os.walk([here])`, c is always 0.
so its not searching.
how do i get it to work?

Comment: This works for me. Is this really the code you are running? What python version are you using?

Comment: python 3... i honestly have no idea what to do... yes. this is the code.

Comment: This works fine in python3.5